# Destroy elements and events

Tags: javascript, dom

Does call `innerHTML = ""` on a DOMElement will destroys all children and all events attached on them ? Or is it required to `delete` manually all of them before to call `innerHTML` to prevent memory consumption ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes `innerHTML` destroys all of it's descendants and the events that were attached go with them.

[Here is an interesting article](http://andrew.hedges.name/blog/2008/04/19/innerhtml-versus-the-dom-cant-we-all-just-get-along) looking at the performance of using `innerHTML` vs DOM replaceChild to add and replace nodes.

**EDIT:** As T.J. Crowder points out, there are issues with earlier versions of IE. Should be nothing to be worried about unless you have requirements to support IE6 (From Frit's answer).

Comment: *"Yes `innerHTML` destroys all of it's descendants and the events that were attached go with them."* There are several important missing caveats to that bald statement.

Answer (score 4):

`delete` has nothing whatsoever to do with memory reclamation or garbage collection in JavaScript (despite its similarity to the keyword used for that in C++).

When you set `innerHTML`, the browser will release its references to all descendant elements of the element you call it on. Normally that means that those elements and any event handlers associated with them are eligible for cleanup, provided nothing else still has any references to them.

There's an issue on older copies of IE where if an element has a handler assigned to it and the handler also has a reference (usually because it's a closure) to the element, that circular reference will keep both the element and the handler in memory even if nothing else has any references to them. So for instance:

```
function foo() {
    var element = document.getElementById("foo");
    element.onclick = function() {
        // ...do something
    };
}
```

Because the anonymous event handler is a closure over the context of the call to `foo`, it has an (implicit) reference to `element`. And of course, `element` has a reference to the handler. This sets up the circle. Older versions of IE can't handle that circle if it crosses the DOM/JavaScript boundary like that.

For that reason, libraries like jQuery and such will actively remove the handler from the element before releasing it (so that the circle is broken).

This isn't an issue with most modern browsers (including very recent versions of IE), which aren't confused by circular references, even when they cross DOM/JavaScript boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

`innerHTML = ""` is simply a way to deference elements. If you still have a reference to some data that lives in those elements the garbage collector might not be able to clean it up.

In general though if you have nothing complex going on this will clean up all the elements and the events. Older browsers are known to be buggy (I think up to IE6) but it should be fine in all modern browser.

Answer (score 0):

`innerHTML=""` will remove them from the DOM, yes. That might make them available for garbage collection, if they are referenced from nowhere else and your browser has not certain memory leaks.

The [`delete` keyword](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/) will certainly not help you.